# Connecting freeswitch remotely using node esl fails

Tags: freeswitch

Im trying to connect remotely to FreeSwitch service using ESL.
Connecting machine and FS Service both are in my local VM's, 2 different VM's

But i get below error

```
[WARNING] mod_event_socket.c:2639 IP 10.95.38.254 Rejected by acl "loopback.auto"
```

/autoload_configs/event_socket.conf.xml

```
<configuration name="event_socket.conf" description="Socket Client">
  <settings>
    <param name="listen-ip" value="0.0.0.0"/>
    <param name="listen-port" value="8021"/>
    <param name="password" value="ClueCon"/>
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

Script:

```
var conn = new esl.Connection('10.191.73.254', 8021, 'ClueCon', function() {

  conn.api('status', function(res) {
    console.log(' >> Connected >> ');
    console.log(res.getBody());
  });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added below lines into acl.config.xml and its working fine

/auto_configs/acl.config.xml

```
<list name="loopback.auto" default="allow">
    <node type="allow" cidr="10.95.38.0/24"/>
</list>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `apply-inbound-acl` explicitly in your `event_socket.conf.xml`. If none is applied, the default loopback ACL is used for ESL.